# When to flag a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags

Back on [Name server registration](https://serverfault.com/questions/103383/name-server-registration/103388), I flagged the comment asking for his post to be marked as accepted.  This was because it is not useful to the conversation, but other than just being tacky, is not really harmful.

Was I correct in doing this?  To me, this is not contributing to the conversation at hand, so it should be removed.  It's not a difference of opinion, contrary facts, etc.  It's just, well, begging.

Comment: This comment is not useful either. But that's part of why we have comments in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a meta-type comment of "please vote my answer up."

Answer (score 6):

I think that for newcomers, it is perfectly fine to nudge them into accepting the correct answer. This does a few things:

1. It teaches them how to use the site.
   If they don't know how to use the site, no better time than the present to teach them. By telling them that they need to do something, like accept an answer, it shows them a feature of the website them might have not known about before, and gets them used to using the site.
2. It gets the coca puffs out of the corn nuts
   Once a question has an accepted mark, almost anywhere you see the question, you will be able to tell if there is an answer to it. Generally people look for questions that are unanswered so they can pipe in and try to provide an answer. By marking an answer as accepted, it is now seen by all that this question has been solved.
3. It rewards the answerer for making a correct answer.
   This of course, is a good thing. As it encourages them to make more correct answers.

I think that better reasons to flag a comment would be if the comment was offensive or obviously spam.

Comment: wait... which ones are the corn nuts?

Comment: The ones not covered in fake chocolate flavor ;-)